# Pronunciation of "compact" across English dialects, when used as different parts of speech

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, parts-of-speech, stress

Googling suggests that *compact* has the stress on the last syllable when used as an adjective and on the first syllable when used as a noun.

Is this common for all English dialects or are there differences for example between British and American English in this regard?

Comment: I don't think there's much dialectal variation per se (though I'm not sure), but the noun is always stressed on the first syllable, the adjective can be stressed on either the first or the last syllable, and the verb is always stressed on the last syllable. As far as I'm aware off the top of my head, this holds for all major dialects.

Comment: Certainly this is the case in BrE. I've not thought of why the adjective goes against the general tendency of two syllable adjectives to be stressed on the first syllable, but I suspect it may be that com- is treated as a prefix.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It's commonly said that Gen Am is more regular in this regard than SSBE, for example. My casual observation would back that up. For example, the nouns *address, cement* which I'm informed have first syllable stress in Gen Am.

Comment: @Araucaria: certainly *address* can have the stress on the first syllable in AmE. I would disagree about *cement*, but I think Southern English is more regular than General American in this respect, and maybe *cement* has first-syllable stress in the South.

Comment: @Araucaria: the noun *cement* has both stress patterns given in *Merriam-Webster*, so it must be accented on the first syllable somewhere in the U.S.

Comment: I've never heard _cement_ with initial stress, either (can't even imagine it!), but it should be noted that many of these initial-stresses in the South are clearly secondary and recent: the words retain full vowels and strong secondary stress in their second syllables. Just think of _PO-lice_, with its long /i/. If the initial stress had been old/original, it would have been like _policy_ without the final vowel.

Comment: The pronunciation SEE-mint was not at all unusual in southern Texas in the 1960s when I lived there, although suh-MINT was probably more common even then. COM-pact was normal for both noun and adjective forms, but I can't remember whether the verb form was pronounced with similar emphasis or the reverse. I have a distinct memory of the verb pronunciations COM-post and cum-POZE, however.

Comment: After the Compact Disc was introduced, I remember holding out for some time with my 'comPACT' pronunciation.  Sadly my one-man crusade proved unsuccessful and I now go with the tide.

Answer (score 2):

Compact (noun—a makeup case) : stress on first syllable

compact (adjective—e.g. "compact car"): equal stress both syllables

compact (verb—e.g. to compact your email folder): stress on second syllable

(American. Yes, there are regional variations)

Answer (score 1):

[According to Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/compact), 'compact' as a verb takes stress on the first syllable when used to mean 'make an agreement with', and takes stress on the second syllable when used to mean 'make smaller'. I would always have stressed the second syllable in either case, but apparently I was incorrect!

Comment: I assume you mean 'second syllable' for the 'make smaller' case?

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of the 'make an agreement' meaning of the word.

Answer (score 0):

It is common in English, whatever the dialect, for some words to be stressed differently when used as different parts of speech.

As far as I know, *compact* has the same stress in BrE and AmE (and, I'm guessing, others).

(And you forgot *compact* as a verb.)